# How might I store graph data in Dexie?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, triplestore, dexie

I'm interested in using Dexie and I'm wondering about relational data. While I found the join example, I'd like to know if there's any existing implementations of Dexie which handle graphs. For example, I'm also interested in Hexastore, which also uses IndexedDB, but appears to be a little out of date.

Should I reimplement Hexastore on top of Dexie?

I'd also like to be able to listen for changes on my data, and I see that Dexie has `dexie-observable`. I found `level-live-stream` but this appears to be abandoned and I haven't had success in fixing it yet.

Also, this example is broken: https://jsfiddle.net/dfahlander/qacL14tu/